# How to print portion of linux filenames that match a regex

Tags: regex, linux, string, awk

I would like to list all files in a linux directory then apply a regular expression on them to format the file name, and print these formatted files names.

Example:

```
ls -lthrh
.
.

-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root   root  633 Oct 31  2016 Oracle_Schedule_ARC-Oracle_ARCH-1477938600005-1002-Oracleorcl-rman1.txt

-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root   root  610 Nov  7  2016 MOD-1478512353102-1002-Oracleorcl-rman1.txt

After applying my regex '.+?(?=-)' I would have everything before the first '-' to be:

Oracle_Schedule_ARC
MOD
```

I've tried using awk, but I couldn't pass a regex to it. I will apply later | sort | uniq to have a unique output of the regex output.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please wrap your sample(s) input and output in CODE TAGS a button `{}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any POSIX shell (`bash`, `pdksh`, `ksh93`, `zsh`, `dash`):

```
for name in *; do
    printf '%s\n' "${name%%-*}"
done
```

This would go through all the names in the current  directory and output the bit before the first `-` character.  It does this by removing the longest suffix string matching `-*` from the filename using a standard parameter substitution.

Note that `-*` is a shell globbing pattern, not a regular expression. Regular expressions are useful for working on text, but globbing patterns are fast and efficient for working with filenames and pathnames in general, as you don't have to start another process with a regex engine, such as `awk` or `sed`.

In `bash`, you could also get away from using a loop at all:

```
set -- *
printf '%s\n' "${@%%-*}"
```

This first sets the positional parameters to the names in the current directory. `printf` is then invoked on the set of names, each individually transformed with the same parameter substitution as in the first part of this answer.

The same thing, but using an array variable other than the array of positional parameters:

```
names=( * )
printf '%s\n' "${names[@]%%-*}"
```

Comment: Why did this get downvoted? It's a pretty slick solution for bash users...

Comment: @Zak Not only `bash` users, but users of any POSIX shell.  I'll make a note about that...

Comment: Good to know :)

Comment: Hah! `set -- *` is fucking cool, but perhaps a bit too arcane. :-)

Comment: I am humbled, educated and entertained, all at the same time.

Comment: @Kusalananda Thank you so much for the detailed explanation!